# How to write a function in reducer in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a React project, In that I have to perform Increment operation and I am writing

That's logic in a store, but I don't now how to stop it's Increment after 6.

So someone please help me how to write logic to stop Incrementing after 6, its initial value

Is 1. When I am clicking the plus icon it has to Increment but it has to stop Incrementing

after number 6. For this project I am using React-Redux.

This is Buttontypes.js

```
export const additionVariable = 'ADDITION'
```

This is Buttonactions.js

```
import { additionVariable }  from './Buttontypes'; 

export const addition = () => {
    return {
        type: additionVariable
    }
}
```

This is Buttonreducer.js

```
import { additionVariable } from './Buttontypes';

const initialState = {
    value: 1
}

const additionReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case additionVariable: return {
            ...state,
            value: state.value + 1
        }
        default: return state
    }
} 

export default additionReducer
```

This is store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './Button/Buttonreducer';

const store = createStore(mainReducer);

export default store
```

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { addition } from './Redux/Button/Buttonactions';

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='adultbox pr-2'>
          <div className='onebox'>
            <span className='adultminus'>-</span>
          </div>
          <div className='twobox'>
            <span className='adultvalue'>{props.value}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='threebox'>
            <span onClick={props.Fun} className='adultplus'>+</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    value: state.value
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    Fun: () => dispatch(addition())
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your reducer :

```js
import { additionVariable } from './Buttontypes';

const initialState = {
    value: 1
}

const additionReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case additionVariable: return {
            ...state,
            value: state.value <= 6 ? state.value + 1 : state.value
        }
        default: return state
    }
} 

export default additionReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what already suggested about the reducer, I would advice you to add a check in mapDispatchToProps and (optional) disable the `+` if the value is equal to 6:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    Fun: (value) => {
        if (value < 6 { 
            dispatch(addition())
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in App.js:

```
<div className='threebox'>
    <span onClick={() => props.Fun(props.value)} className='adultplus'>+</span>
</div>
```